# Laravel 5.4 - Error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()

Tags: laravel-5.4

How do you fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tzIH.png)

Comment: Add some code over here, I know the issue but first add some of your efforts

Comment: Need to clear your code by posting code related to your problem.

Comment: https://www.rmu.ac.th/change/en

Comment: Code should be posted in the original post incase the original link stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **put()** method in order to write to session store.